# NativeScript UI doesn't respond to propertyChange of Observable when repeating changes

Tags: observable, nativescript

It must be something I oversee, but when I change a property (which is an object) of an Observable the first time the UI is updated as expected. But the second time I see no change though the observable is changed and has send a notification (I see this in the receiveNotification function).
See the code below, the change is made via a dialog and the unitTap function. What am I missing here?

```
var pageData;

function setPageData (product) {
    pageData = new Observable({
        units: restClientUnits.viewModelArray,
        vatpercentages: restClientVatPercentages.viewModelArray,
        product: product
    });
    loadLists();
}

function receiveNotification(args) {
    console.log("Notification received...");
    console.log(args.propertyName);
    console.log(args.value.unit);
}

exports.loaded = function(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var product = page.navigationContext;
    //Extra listener just to check if notification is send
    product.addEventListener(Observable.propertyChangeEvent, receiveNotification, this);
    setPageData(product);
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
};

exports.unitTap = function() {
    var unitNames = [];
    pageData.get("units").forEach(function(unit) {
       unitNames.push(unit.get("unit"));
    });
    dialogs.action({
        message: "Select unit",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
        actions: unitNames,
    }).then(function (result) {
        pageData.get("units").forEach(function(obj) {
                if (obj.unit === result) {
                    pageData.get("product").set("unit", obj);
                }
        });
        console.log("New set unit: " + pageData.get("product").get("unit").unit);
        console.log("Dialog result: " + result)
    });
};
```

```
<Page.actionBar>
    <ActionBar title="Products">
        <NavigationButton text="go back" android.systemIcon = "ic_menu_back" tap="goBack"/>
        <ActionBar.actionItems>
            <ActionItem text="Save" position="right" tap="save"/>
        </ActionBar.actionItems>
    </ActionBar>
</Page.actionBar>
<StackLayout>
    <GridLayout cols="*" rows="auto, auto">
        <Label text="productnaam: " cssClass="field-title" />
        <TextField text="{{ product.productName }}" cssClass="field" row="1" col="1" />
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout cols="*" rows="auto, auto">
        <Label text="beschrijving: " cssClass="field-title" />
        <TextView text="{{ product.description }}" cssClass="field" row="1" col="1" />
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout cols="*" rows="auto, auto">
        <Label text="Prijs per eenheid: " cssClass="field-title"/>
        <TextField text="{{ product.unitPrice }}" cssClass="field" row="1" col="1"/>
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout cols="*" rows="auto, auto">
        <Label text="eenheid: " col="0" cssClass="field-title"/>
        <TextField text="{{ product.unit.unit }}" cssClass="field" row="1" col="1" editable="false" tap="unitTap"/>
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout cols="*" rows="auto, auto">
        <Label text="btw percentage: " cssClass="field-title"/>
        <TextField text="{{ product.vatPercentage.vatPercentage }}" cssClass="field" row="1" col="1" tap="showModal"/>
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well well, I am my own rubber duck...

Look at these two examples and see the shocking difference:

obs.xml version 1:

```
<Page loaded="loaded">
    <StackLayout>
    <TextField text="{{ item.seconds }}"/>
    <TextField text="{{ item.secondsobject.seconds}}"/>
    <Button text="Increase" tap="increaseSeconds"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

obs.js version 1:

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

var pageData = new Observable({
    item: new Observable({seconds: 1, secondsobject: {seconds: 1}})
});

var page;
exports.loaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
};

exports.increaseSeconds = function() {
    pageData.item.set("seconds", pageData.item.seconds + 1);
    var newValue = pageData.item.secondsobject.seconds + 1;
    pageData.item.set("secondsobject",{seconds: newValue});
};
```

obs.xml version 2:

```
<Page loaded="loaded">
    <StackLayout>
    <TextField text="{{ item.seconds }}"/>
    <TextField text="{{ item.secondsobject.secondsobject}}"/>
    <Button text="Increase" tap="increaseSeconds"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

obs.js version 2:

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

var pageData = new Observable({
    item: new Observable({seconds: 1, secondsobject: {secondsobject: 1}})
});

var page;
exports.loaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
};

exports.increaseSeconds = function() {
    pageData.item.set("seconds", pageData.item.seconds + 1);
    var newValue = pageData.item.secondsobject.secondsobject + 1;
    pageData.item.set("secondsobject",{secondsobject: newValue});
};
```

Version 1 works as intended, both fields are updated with the new value on each button click. Version 2 only updates the field 'item.secondsobject.secondsobject' on the first click and ignores the updated value on consecutive clicks.
So apparently, Nativescript's databinding doesn't properly handle objects that have properties which in turn also have a property with the same name...

Comment: That really sounds as a bug - can you open an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues) so that the team can take a closer look at it.

Comment: Alexander, I didn't have the time to that the past days, but I just did now.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the `product` object you are getting from the nav-context is not an observable itself. I can see that you are creating and `Observable` for the `pageData` but that will not automatically make all its field observable also.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, but (unfortunately) that's not the problem. The product object passed as context is an Observable. I checked and double checked that. Besides, the strange thing is that the UI gets updated the first time changing the unit field. The only thing that changes from a non-Observable to an Observable is the unit object that is replaced as property of the product. But I also tried to update the unit property with a plain object. That didn't do the trick.

Comment: Sorry. Can you post the XML also?

Comment: Sure. I've updated the original post. The strange thing is that I **_do_** see the notifcation of the propertyChange